# Understanding this template function

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand a class file in order to integrate my own written codes with it, but I had some difficulties in understanding this template function and I couldn't find out what would be the output of this function.

```
template <typename Key, typename Value> struct PriorityItem {
  Key key;
  Value value;
  PriorityItem() {}
  PriorityItem(Key const& key, Value const& value) : key(key), value(value) {
  }
  bool operator<(PriorityItem const& pi) const {
    if (key == pi.key)
      return value < pi.value;
    return key < pi.key;
  }
};
```

I can understand that this template is getting two inputs and initializes them. Then if I don't mistake it is becoming some sort of recursive function, but what does `pi.key` or `pi.value` mean?

Is it really a recursive function?

Why it is returning a comparison form, and what is output of this?

Comment: `pi` is the `PriorityItem` you are comparing with, the `pi.value` and `pi.key` are its members. `value` and `key` are equivalent to `this->value` and `this->key`.

Comment: In general, operator< is implemented in order to use containers like std::set or std::priority_queue. I think  the key is like a name, and the value is used to define the priority of the elements with the same name.

Comment: Yeah, it's not meant to be a recursive function. It's not calling itself, it's returning the result of either value < pi.value pr key < pi.key. It's returning a bool, and we have no idea what the output is. It's basically saying: "A is greater than B if A's key is greater than B's key. If the keys are equal, then A is greater than B if A's value is greater than B's value."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a recursive function....

Allow me to copy and add comments inside:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value> 
struct PriorityItem {   // This is a struct template, it takes two type parameters Key and Value
  Key key; // Key is an attribute of the struct and is of type Key (one of the template parameters)
  Value value; // Value is an attribute of the struct and is of type Value (the second template parameter)
  PriorityItem() {} // This is the default constructor. 
                    // It relies on Key and Value types to have proper constructors     
                    // in order to initialize the key and value attributes.
  PriorityItem(Key const& key, Value const& value) : key(key), value(value) {
                    // This is parameter constructor. It provides values
                    // to both attributes and assigns them in the initializer list.
  }
  bool operator<(PriorityItem const& pi) const {
     // This is an operator< method. It allows to do things like :
     //     PriorityItem<A,B> a;
     //     PriorityItem<A,B> b;
     //     ...
     //     if(a < b) { ... }
     //

     // the comparison relationship goes as follows:
     if (key == pi.key)          // If key attribute is the same in both, PriorityItems...
        return value < pi.value; // then follow the order of the value attributes.
     return key < pi.key;        // Otherwise, follow the order of the key attributes.

  }
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Nothing about this class is recursive. The `PriorityItem(Key const& key, Value const& value)` constructor is just initializing the member variables with the same values passed in as arguments. This is what the `key(key)` and `value(value)` stands for. Those are constructor operators for the memeber variables with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

Key and value are the instantiated object's member variables. The pi.key and pi.value variables are of the object you are using to compare the instantiated one with. What the function does is compare the keys first and if the keys are the same, it compares the objects depending on their values.